# Codemirror how to create a mode

Tags: javascript, regex, editor, codemirror, codemirror-modes

So I just got into codemirror recently because I needed a text editor for my website, but that means I don't know much about the program. I got the editor working with the javascript mode, but I need to create some syntax for the editor, which I believe means I have to create a mode for the editor, and I am having trouble doing this. I have read over the manual a few times but something just isn't clicking for me, probably because I've never worked with something like this. Anyways right now I just need to get the hang of it, by creating simple add, subtract, and multiply functions. if someone could get me rolling with this I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, are you sure you need a new mode?  Are you trying to support some custom [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) syntax that isn't already provided by one of the many built in modes?

The [Manual](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi) has a good start on information for this.  It mentions the simple case of using the [simple mode addon](https://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html) for a declarative approach. It discusses the use of `CodeMirror.defineMode` to create a new mode and mentions the most important function for mode development `token(stream, state)`:

> a function that takes a character stream as input, advances it past a token, and returns a style for that token.

The manual also gives two example modes to look at.  For a really simple mode it recommends [diff](https://codemirror.net/mode/diff/diff.js) and for a more complex mode [clike](https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js).  It is also worth just looking at the available modes in the mode directory to see if you can't just modify an existing mode to fit your needs.

Just for your reference I will include the diff mode inline below:

```
// CodeMirror, copyright (c) by Marijn Haverbeke and others
// Distributed under an MIT license: http://codemirror.net/LICENSE

(function(mod) {
  if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
    mod(require("../../lib/codemirror"));
  else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
    define(["../../lib/codemirror"], mod);
  else // Plain browser env
    mod(CodeMirror);
})(function(CodeMirror) {
"use strict";

CodeMirror.defineMode("diff", function() {

  var TOKEN_NAMES = {
    '+': 'positive',
    '-': 'negative',
    '@': 'meta'
  };

  return {
    token: function(stream) {
      var tw_pos = stream.string.search(/[\t ]+?$/);

      if (!stream.sol() || tw_pos === 0) {
        stream.skipToEnd();
        return ("error " + (
          TOKEN_NAMES[stream.string.charAt(0)] || '')).replace(/ $/, '');
      }

      var token_name = TOKEN_NAMES[stream.peek()] || stream.skipToEnd();

      if (tw_pos === -1) {
        stream.skipToEnd();
      } else {
        stream.pos = tw_pos;
      }

      return token_name;
    }
  };
});

CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/x-diff", "diff");

});
```

This is a very simple mode that doesn't even include any state information (and thus doesn't include the second param to the 'token' method).

I hope this helps.

Comment: A lot of great information, only thing im hung up on is why the simple mode looks so different from the diff mode?

Comment: **Diff** mode **is a** simple mode to start from.  The **simple mode addon** is a more generic utility mode to allow you to create a mode from a declarative format, and thus is intended to be generic enough to support some simple modes you may encounter without the requirement to write your own mode.  The addon isn't as flexible as writing your own mode from scratch, which is what the **diff** mode is, albeit a very simple mode.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm still lost on how I'm going to make this work but that's just because this is all so new to me but you definitely put me on the right path

Comment: No problem.  This sort of thing isn't that easy to jump into, so don't feel discouraged for sure.  It may be helpful for you to set a few breakpoints in the mode logic in your browser's development tools and step through it.  The main duty of the `token` function is to parse the stream and return a CSS style for the token it encounters.  If you are new to regular expressions I would recommend checking out [this site](http://www.regexr.com/).